# Using Async with WebAPI2 and Entity Framework 6 with .Net 4.6

Tags: c#, entity-framework, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

I had set up my controller and service layer to not use async and Task originally.  I updated my code (below).  Is this the correct way to use async, Task, and await?  Will my code benefit long term as number of users grow?

Controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> All()
{
    var warmup = await _warmupService.GetAllAsync();

    if (warmup != null)
        return Ok(warmup);

    return NotFound();
}
```

The Controller calls this method in my service layer:

```
public async Task<Warmup> GetAllAsync()
{            
    return await Task.Run(() => GetWarmup());
}
```

GetWarmup() (also in Service) makes a DB call using EF6:

```
private Warmup GetWarmup()
{
    var warmup = new Warmup();

    var factoryTools = _db.FactoryTools.Select(tool => new { tool.Factory });
}
```

Comment: You're asking if its correct?  What happens when you run it?  Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not the best way to do it. If you can, avoid using `Task.Run` when your underlying code provides a `Task` or `Task<T>` you can await.

Instead of using `Task.Run` in this piece of code

```
public async Task<Warmup> GetAllAsync()
{            
    return await Task.Run(() => GetWarmup());
}
```

and using this:

```
private Warmup GetWarmup()
{
    var warmup = new Warmup();

    var factoryTools = _db.FactoryTools.Select(tool => new { tool.Factory });
}
```

you should use the native async methods provided by the Entity Framework like demoed here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819165(v=vs.113).aspx

So your `GetWarmUp()` should be `async Task<Warmup>()` and call one of the native async methods of the Entity Framework.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.queryableextensions(v=vs.113).aspx for a list of available async extension methods.